# Calculating rolling Root Mean Square Error in python

Tags: python, pandas, apply, rolling-computation

Suppose I have a pandas data frame, `vols` where

```
vols.head()

             Return     Vol
DataDate        
2019-12-26  0.002291    0.002400
2019-12-27  0.002292    0.002392
2019-12-30  0.002288    0.002385
2019-12-31  0.002288    0.002378
2020-01-01  0.002286    0.002378
```

Next I rename `vols` columns.

```
vols.columns = ['Realized', 'Predicted']
vols.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 922 entries, 2019-12-26 to 2023-07-27
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------     --------------  -----  
 0   Realized   922 non-null    float64
 1   Predicted  922 non-null    float64
dtypes: float64(2)
```

I want to calculate rolling Root Mean Square Error.

```
vols_rolling = vols.rolling(window=52)

from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error as mse

vols_rolling.apply(lambda x: mse(x['Realized'], x['Predicted']))
```

I am getting following `ValueError`.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslibs\parsing.pyx:440, in pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.parse_datetime_string_with_reso()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslibs\parsing.pyx:649, in pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.dateutil_parse()

ValueError: Unknown datetime string format, unable to parse: Realized

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

The error is quite long. Trying not to copy paste it here.

Comment: can you please share the entire traceback / error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that [`rolling.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html) works **per column**, but your function need to access two columns simultaneously.

You can cheat and use one Series to retrieve the index and slice the external DataFrame:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error as mse

vols_rolling = vols.rolling(window=52, min_periods=1)

vols_rolling['Realized'].apply(lambda x: mse(vols.loc[x.index, 'Realized'], vols.loc[x.index, 'Predicted']))
```

Output:

```
DataDate
2019-12-26    1.188100e-08
2019-12-27    1.094050e-08
2019-12-30    1.043000e-08
2019-12-31    9.847500e-09
2020-01-01    9.570800e-09
Name: Realized, dtype: float64
```